# Routing dynamic Paths recursively in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I want to build something like a directory browser with AngularJS. Is is possible to route paths with ng-route? I'd like to parse URLs like this: myapp.com/#/folder1/folder2/.../folderN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [$routeProvider docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

> path can contain named groups starting with a colon and ending with a
>   star: e.g.:name*. All characters are eagerly stored in $routeParams
>   under the given name when the route matches.

So you could define

```
$routeProvider.when('/:folders*', {
    template:'template'
})
```

And then (in controller e.g.)

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
    if (angular.isDefined($routeParams.folders))
        var foldersArray = $routeParams.folders.split('/');
});
```

DEMO JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/rYm5G/