# Angular nested resources data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following code:

```js
//routes
.state('app.parent', {
  url: '/parent',
  templateUrl: 'parent.html',
  controller: 'ParentCtrl'
})
.state('app.parent.child', {
  url: '/child',
  controller: 'ChildCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'child.html',
})


//controllers
.controller('ParentCtrl', ['$scope', 'SomeResource', function ($scope, SomeResource) {
  $scope.resources = [];
  
  SomeResource.query({}, function(data) {
    $scope.resources = data;
  });
}])
.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope', 'OtherResource', function ($scope, OtherResource) {
  $scope.other = {};
  ...
}])
```

```html
<!-- VIEWSs -->
<!-- parent.html -->
...
<div ui-view>
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="resource in resources">
        ...
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- child.html -->
<div class="form">
 ...
</div>
```

And, some other nested states.

The problem is when I access any "child" state of "parent", the parent controller is apparently always executed, so a call to **SomeResource.query** is called for every child state.

I need the ***query*** just for the parent not for any child state, and need it nested.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using nested states by definition call all nested controller.

Comment: does something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985259/routing-dynamic-paths-recursively-in-angularjs) work?

Comment: @Thom-x no, that is backwards

Comment: would using `cache:true` help on parent query resource?

Comment: Probably it is worth to look at ui router (replaces standart router). It has some cool features, e.g. partial views. And it would fit your case, because for nested states it only inherits resolved dependencies and data.

Comment: @charlietfl, doesn't help, thanks.

Comment: @JanisP, I'm using uiRouter: $stateProvider.state

Comment: @JanisP OP already using ui-router. ngRoute doesn't use `state()` and doesn't support nesting

Comment: Ohh... my bad, didn't saw named states. Anyway to make it up: http://plnkr.co/edit/LEhoJ1WbKaTqlveWUClq?p=info here is small plunker that shows how I achieved it. Basically I assigned controllers on view level, not state level. And then only necessary controller is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As per [angular-ui docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views),

> When the application is in a particular state—when a state is "active"—all of its ancestor states are implicitly active as well. Below, when the "contacts.list" state is active, the "contacts" state is implicitly active as well, because it's the parent state to "contacts.list".

Which means if you don’t need the parent to be active when the child is accessed, don’t use nesting. (Your URL structure lacks nesting as well which might be a sign you don’t need it in your state structure.)

If you do want to nest states for other reasons, and you simply want to avoid an expensive query running more than once, you might want to refactor your `SomeResource` implementation. For example, you can add some caching within that service so that repeat calls to `query()` don’t cause overhead.